# How to write a function that will roughly return numbers in this pattern?

Tags: functions

I feel ashamed but I am willing to learn. How do I write a function to get this results for given x?

I need a quadratic function right?

for x = 0, return 1

for x = 20, return 1.5

for x = 30, return 2

Comment: See [Polynomial Interpolation](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=Polynomial+Interpolation) and [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=InterpolatingPolynomial%5B%7B%7B0%2C1%7D%2C+%7B20%2C+1.5%7D%2C+%7B30%2C+2%7D%7D%2C+x%5D).

Comment: There are many functions with this property... Do you look for a special one? A polynomial?

Comment: In theory there are an infinite number of functions including f(x) = 0 unless x = 0, 20 or 30 in which case f(x) = 1, 1.5 and 2.  The question is which function is the simplest for you situation and like to to do what you want.  What type of data is this describing?

Comment: What properties are you hoping to get? What is this for? Do you want something which, for instance, grows forever, but vanishingly quickly? Or something which grows towards a bound? Are you more interested in the behavior for small $x$ or large $x$?

Comment: @GitGud Thank you! This just works. It is truly astonishing from my point of view. I am finding myself being fascinated by math at age 25 :)

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of them.  The hard part is picking one.  For $n$ points you can always find an $n-1$ degree polynomial through them.  In your case, it would be a quadratic, so just write $$f(0)=1=a(0)^2+b(0)+c\\f(20)=1.5=a(20)^2+b(20)+c\\f(30)=2=a(30)^2+b(30)+c$$  You can see $c=1$ from the first and solve the other two to give $a=1/1200,b=1/120$  You can use any functional form you want.  If it has three adjustable parameters (like the $a,b,c$) above you will get three equations in three unknowns.  This one is an upward opening parabola.  Maybe you want a horizontal asymptote instead?  You could use $f(x)=a+b(\frac 1{x+c})$  You can use goal seek in Excel to find the parameters.

Comment: Thank you, I think this is 100% correct and it helped me understand the problem better. I have chosen to use polynomial interpolation. Have a great day my friend!